# Powershell - split string to array delineated by start and end strings

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, split

I have a multi-line string (from a json) like

```
"somekey": "somevalue",
"somekey": "somevalue"
"somekey": [somevalue]
"somekey": somenumber
"somekey": null,
```

I'd like to split the string into an array, where the value of each element is either the value of somevalue or somenumber.  (I'm essentially forming an array containing the values of every value that appears in a json)

This should yield the following element values:

```
somevalue
somevalue
somevalue
somenumber
```

I've played with variations and additions to, the followning code:

```
$jsonValues = $jsonValues.Split(": ").Split([Environment]::NewLine)
```

but wondering about the most eloquent way to achieve this.

Comment: is that one multiline string or an array of strings?

Comment: presuming you have a multiline string, and it is stored in `$InStuff`, this works ... >>> `$InStuff.Split(':').Trim().Trim('",][').Where({$_})` <<<

Comment: Thanks Lee, I should have added that actually the string is multiline and each line contains some key. All I need is to collect the values to an array, and delineate past the keys. I've updated the question to reflect. Your code works, but also gives me the keys as array value items too

Comment: you are welcome! [*grin*] ///// the `.Split()` method DOES NOT split on the string in parens ... it splits on each character in that string. here's another stab at it ... >>> `($InStuff -split [System.Environment]::NewLine).ForEach({$_.Split(':')[-1]}).Trim(' ",][')` <<<

Comment: Your input is generally valid JSON? `[somevalue]` doesn't seem to fit - did you mean `[ "somevalue" ]`, or did you just mean represent an array with arbitrary values and an arbitrary count of elements?

Comment: Thanks @Lee_Dailey your solution came closest. It yeilded more matches than mine! Will reference that as the answer

Comment: @mklement0 The idea was originally to take a json, and try to grab every value from it whereever it was, and put it into an array of arbitrary values. Had to do some slicing of parts off the raw data first. Though there may have been a more optimal way of grabbing every value from json that through raw string searching, splitting, trimming etc.

Comment: @david - you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that generically extracts all leaf property values from a JSON document, using proper JSON parsing via [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json):

```
# Accepts a JSON string and outputs all leaf property values.
function Get-JsonValue {
  param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $json)

  begin {
    # Helper function that walks the object graph.
    function walk {
      param($obj)

      # Note: @(...) is used so that scalar $null values aren't ignored.
      foreach ($elem in @($obj)) {
        if ($elem -isnot [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) { 
          $elem # leaf value -> output
        }
        else {
          # recurse
          foreach ($prop in $elem.psobject.Properties) {
            foreach ($subElem in @($prop.Value)) { walk $subElem }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  process {
    walk ($json | ConvertFrom-Json)
  }

}

# Sample JSON input
$json = @'
  [ { "hi": 11 }, {
    "somekey1": "somevalue1",
    "somekey2": "somevalue2",
    "somekey3": 42,
    "somekey4": [
        "somevalue4.1",
        "somevalue4.2",
        4.42
      ],
    "somekey5": null
  } ]
'@


# Call with the sample string
$json | Get-JsonValue
```

The above yields the following:

```
11
somevalue1
somevalue2
42
somevalue4.1
somevalue4.2
4.42
# $null - not visible
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lee_Dailey - his filter produced the most results for me in grabbing all values from raw json to an array.

```
($InStuff -split [System.Environment]::NewLine).ForEach({$_.Split(':')[-1]}).Trim(' ",][')
```